How to Maintain Original Image/Video Resolution
I am currently facing an issue with image and video attachments in Odoo. Whenever I attach an image or video with high resolution, it gets automatically compressed and its size is significantly reduced. This is affecting the quality of the media files that I need to maintain.
I have multiple options to address this:

Stop the automatic compression process entirely and allow the files to be saved in their original size and resolution.

If the image is uploaded with a high resolution, compress it only to a maximum of 1000px without reducing the image below 1000px if it is initially larger than 1000px.

We can store media directly to a local folder of the system without compromising size and resolution, and whenever the user wants, they can access it directly.
Any guidance on achieving either of these solutions would be greatly appreciated. If there are any specific settings, modules, or customizations required.


Thank you in advance for your help!

Create a custom module or modify the existing ir_attachment model to prevent compression.
from odoo import models, fields

class IrAttachment(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'ir.attachment'

    def _compute_image(self, vals):
        # Override the default method to prevent image compression
        return vals


